# Loss of prompt colors after entering and exiting a root prompt

Tags: command-line, root

When entering and exiting a root prompt, my terminal does not return the usual prompt colors:

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: after]

The first image is my terminal after exiting the root steel and the second the one I would like to see.

---

I tried to search on forums

Comment: Do you mean like the colors in the output of commands like `ls`?

Comment: Can you reproduce the steps you're following to get the root prompt and exit again?

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu now recommend against even setting a root password or running as root, vs. sudoers list and `sudo` for root privilege?  Thought it was that way as long ago as 16.04, maybe 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot of where to start. You need to add and edit your profiles.

[image: Terminal preferences]

Comment: I tried did this. But doesn't work. What is the correct configuration? please

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. It works for me.

Comment: first, thanks for listening. But a doubt, which setting did you choose to return the color?

Comment: I am not totally sure.  I use Kubuntu normally.  But I know the setting is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it: go to terminal and type:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

If you don't have nano then install it with this command:

```
sudo apt install nano
```

Then find this line:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

If it has a # before it, just delete the #.
If it's set to no, then make it yes.

Then press: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

After that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Now just execute this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Done!

Note: To get colored prompt on every user, you have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is why:

```
[15:33:53] root@host: ~
0 # cat /root/.bashrc | grep -C 2 TERM

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
--

[15:34:16] root@host: ~
0 # cat /home/user/.bashrc | grep -C 2 TERM

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
--
```

For root the condition is different and since we've got:

```
[15:35:15] root@host: ~
0 # echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

we end up with the difference between root and regular user.